# Trigonometry Prove sec x

Tags: trigonometry

$\frac{1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}{1-\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}} = \sec x$

The parentheses are to help you see that its tan/tan equals sec x

Can some one please help me prove this?

Comment: This site uses MathJax and supports both Inline and Block equation notation. Please, try to edit your post so as to use these features; it helps us better understand what you are trying to ask. Also, could you show your progress so far?

Comment: Try to make use of these identities: $1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$ and $\cos^22x = \cos^2x -\sin^2x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1+\tan^2 (x/2)}{1-\tan^2 (x/2)}=\frac{\cos^2(x/2)+\sin^2 (x/2)}{\cos^2(x/2)-\sin^2 (x/2)}=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x/2)-\sin^2 (x/2)}=\frac{1}{\cos x}=\sec x$$